# How to a request to another webserver

Tags: http, http-headers, webserver

I have following scenario:

[image]

The client request for web content to the web server.
But sometimes the client use data from SAP server and make an OData request to SAP server.

How to forward OData request from the client through the webserver to SAP server? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

U can recreate the request to the SAP server in your own web server. As soon as the client triggers the request your web service triggers the sap request. The web server waits for the response from the SAP server and return this response to the client.